# $A.createComponent not firing when loading component dynamically

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, promises

I have a parent custom component which loads child custom components dynamically to create a non linear interview/wizard process.

The child component has `aura:valueInit` method:

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
```

Which fires this method:

```
doInit : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    console.log("doInit");
    // do other stuff
},
```

The parent component uses this method to dynamically load the child:

```
injectComponent: function (cmp, name) {
    console.log('injectComponent');

    var target = cmp.find('main');

    $A.createComponent(name, {
        "aura:id" : "activeScreen",
        "model" :  this.model(cmp)
    }, function (contentComponent, status, error) {
        if (status === "SUCCESS") {
            console.log('injectComponent: SUCCESS');
            target.set('v.body', [contentComponent]);
        } else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
            console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
        } else if (status === "ERROR") {
            console.log(error);
            throw new Error(error);
        }
    });
},
```

And `injectComponent` is called from here:

```
    Promise.all([savePromise]).then(function(values) {
        var next = self.getNextScreen(cmp, model);
        self.injectComponent(cmp, next);
    });
```

But when I call `injectComponent` it stalls, and the component does **not** render until I click somewhere on the screen.

Here is an example of the console log:

[image]

Notice the 10 second gap between `injectComponent` and `doInit`

Why is this happening?

Comment: What code do you call injectComponent from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed it by adding `$A.getCallback(` after the `.then`

```
Promise.all([savePromise]).then($A.getCallback(function(values) {
    self.injectComponent(cmp, next);
}));
```

For further info:

- [Using JavaScript Promises](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_promises.htm)
- [Modifying Components Outside the Framework Lifecycle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm)